# Is it possible to get posts with specific hashtag using linkedin API?

Tags: linkedin-api

I have read through almost all of the documentation of the api v2, and hashtags are not mentioned anywhere. If not, is it possible to get public posts (from both companies and regular users) filtered with a specific keyword?

Comment: did you find anything?

Comment: im afraid not. we opted to go with another way instead of the api